# Flask guess game not responding correctly

Tags: python, html, flask

I am strugling with below. Not sure what is going on but i can see no reaction on the site while submiting. I tried moving the maximum and minimum variables from inside the function to outisde. It looks like guess variable is not used properly here but i have no clue what is going on.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

minimum = 0
maximum = 1000
guess = int((maximum - minimum) / 2) + minimum

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def zadanie():
    global maximum
    global minimum
    global guess
    if request.method == 'POST':
        guess = int((maximum - minimum) / 2) + minimum
        odp = request.form['odp']
        if odp == 'Zgadłeś':
            render_template('Zadanie_3_1.html', g=f'WYGRAŁEM! Twoja liczba to {guess}')
        elif odp == 'Zadużo':
            maximum = guess
            render_template('Zadanie_3_1.html', g=f'Czy twoja liczba to: {guess}')
        elif odp == 'Zamało':
            minimum = guess
            render_template('Zadanie_3_1.html', g=f'Czy twoja liczba to: {guess}')
        else:
            render_template('Zadanie_3_1.html', g=f'NIE OSZUKUJ')
    return render_template('Zadanie_3_1.html', g=f'Zgaduje: {guess}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Zadanie_3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pomyśl liczbe od 0 do 1000</h1>
    <br>
    <h3>{{ g }}</h3>
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('zadanie') }}">
        <hidden></hidden>
        <p>
            <br>
            <label>
                <!--<input type="hidden" name="minimum" value="0">-->
                <!--<input type="hidden" name="maximum" value="1000">-->
                <input type="radio" name="odp" value="Zadużo">Za dużo</input> <br>
                <input type="radio" name="odp" value="Zamało">Za mało</input> <br>
                <input type="radio" name="odp" value="Zgadłeś">Zgadłeś</input> <br>
            </label>
        </p>
        <label>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Wyślij">
        </label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `<form action="/" method="POST">` to `<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('zadanie') }}">`?

Comment: Oh, and for the purposes of testing to try pin the issue down, change `<button type="submit">Wyślij</button>` to `<input type="submit" value="Wyślij">`?

Comment: My HTML knowledge is not great so I cannot give a definitive reason why, but I think if you want to have a button there you still need it as an `<input>` tag but set the class as a button

Comment: Having globals in a Flask app is generally going to be a bad idea, but I think you'll need to start debugging that one on your end now

Comment: Please put all relevant details in the body of the question with an [edit] as comments can be deleted. In short, you need to debug this and tell us what your research has uncovered.

Comment: Added suggested changes. Site seem to respond yet with not expected results. My number is 300. On first submit i choose 'Za duzo' it responds again with the same 500, on second submit i again choose 'Za duzo' it responds with 250 which is desired. On 3rd submit i choose 'Za mało' it shows 125 instead of 375.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but i noticed that **return** added before render_template under 'POST' condition fixed the issue.

---

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

minimum = 0
maximum = 1000


@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def zadanie():
    global maximum
    global minimum
    guess = int(((maximum - minimum) / 2) + minimum)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        odp = request.form['odp']
        if odp == 'Zgadłeś':
            return render_template('Zgadywanie_liczb_3.html', g=f'WYGRAŁEM! Twoja liczba to {guess}')
        elif odp == 'Zadużo':
            maximum = guess
            guess = int(((maximum - minimum) / 2) + minimum)
            return render_template('Zgadywanie_liczb_3.html', g=f'Czy twoja liczba to: {guess}')
        elif odp == 'Zamało':
            minimum = guess
            guess = int(((maximum - minimum) / 2) + minimum)
            return render_template('Zgadywanie_liczb_3.html', g=f'Czy twoja liczba to: {guess}')
        else:
            return render_template('Zgadywanie_liczb_3.html', g=f'NIE OSZUKUJ')
    else:
        return render_template('Zgadywanie_liczb_3.html', g=f'Zgaduje: {guess}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```